# Cannot read property 'api'

Tags: aurelia, ag-grid

I'm trying to define the columns.

```
import { GridOptions } from "ag-grid-community";
import "ag-grid-enterprise";
......
private gridOptions:GridOptions;
.....here I fill columdDefs
this.gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs(columnDefs);
```

but when I execute I get this error.

```
Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'api' of undefined    at HoursDataTable.defineColumns
```

Any idea please?
Regards

Answer (score 1):

Solved adding this

```
this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{};
```

Thanks